# Does Baleyworld feature in any of the Foundation Series books (perhaps under a different name)?

Tags: isaac-asimov, foundation

Does Baleyworld (from Robots and Empire) feature in any of the Foundation Series books (perhaps under a different name)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Comporellon](http://asimov.wikia.com/wiki/Comporellon)

> Comporellon, originally Baleyworld, was a planet near Gaia and
>   Sayshell that was renowned for its particularly old age. It was
>   founded by the second wave of space colonists, known as the Settlers,
>   and thus had a very superstitious attitude toward the first wave, the
>   Spacers. They were also superstitious about Earth.
>
> Golan Trevize, Janov Pelorat, and Bliss visit Comporellon in
>   [Foundation and Earth](http://asimov.wikia.com/wiki/Foundation_and_Earth), and acquire the coordinates of three Spacer
>   worlds: Solaria, Aurora, and Melpomenia from a historian.